# Hasselblad 503CXi Loose Film speed selector

Tags: film, hasselblad

I recently purchased a beautiful Hasselblad 503CXi and I am in love with it! However, the film speed selector is loose. Am I right in believing that the selector has no affect in normal (non-metered) operation of the camera? Does it only communicate with the flash sync cable, or does it also talk to a metered prism finder?

Hope this question is clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Hasselblad 5xx cameras are completely mechanical in operation. Every setting is set manually, mostly on the lens. The metering prism is completely autonomous - you have to set everything manually, even the speed of the attached lens.

The ISO selector controls only the TTL flash, and only for a couple compatible Metz flashes with special connector cables. So it is of very little use in most current use cases.

Assuming you are using the camera with a waist level finder and no flash the dial is just for show. It is even poor reminder of film speed used, as most people just stick the flap of a film packet to the little indicator window on the back of the magazine.